# How to parametrize an Ember View?

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember view like this:

```
App.DateView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "_date",
    tagName: 'span',
    classNames: ['calendar-date'],
    attributeBindings: ['placement:data-placement', 'title'],
    placement: 'right',

    didInsertElement: function(){
        this.$().tooltip();
    },
});
```

My template is:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_date">
  {{calendar date}}
</script>
```

How can I bind the date on the "_date" template when calling the `view` helper? Can I do something like this?

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="other">
  {{view App.DateView date="starts"}}
  {{view App.DateView date="ends"}}
</script>
```

Here `starts` and `ends` are accesible properties of the model. The example above doesn't work.

Comment: I want to do this to reuse the DateView for different model fields without writing a view for every field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your sample you are missing to register the `calendar` helper, and specify the correct context in the template. Because the default context of the view is the controller you need to use the `view` property to access the view properties:

```
{{calendar view.date}}
```

But, because you want to create a reusable component I recommend you to use the [ember components](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html), because it's intended for this purpose, so you don't need to use `view` since the context is the view itself:

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/date-view">    
    {{input type="date" valueBinding="date"}}
</script>
```

Component:

```
App.DateViewComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    date: null,
    tagName: 'span',
    classNames: ['calendar-date'],
    attributeBindings: ['data-placement', 'title'],
    'data-placement': 'right',
    didInsertElement: function(){        
        //this.$().tooltip();
    }
});
```

So in some template you can use multiple times, for example:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    Selected start: {{start}}<br/>      
    Selected end: {{end}}<br/>    
    Start: {{date-view dateBinding="start"}}<br/>      
    End: {{date-view dateBinding="end"}}<br/>      
</script>
```

This is a demo of this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/eBXKe/

I hope it helps